# Interesting Invalid or unexpected token - JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

So lately I've been running a lot of jQuery on my Wordpress sites. Ive been getting the error of "Invalid or unexpected token" a lot, and found what causes it, just maybe looking for a way to fix it.

So basically this doesnt work:

```
jQuery(".someClass").prepend("
            <h2>Some text</h2>     ");
```

But this does:

```
jQuery(".someClass").prepend("<h2>Some text</h2>");
```

What makes it a bit hard for me is that my code is sometimes being echo'ed by php, so the above code is a result of this:

```
$descriptionHeadJQuery = '<script>
jQuery(".portfolio_images").prepend("' . $descriptionHead . '");</script>';
```

I'm sure I can get all the spacing right and the line breaks to get it to work properly, but I'm also sure that there is someone out here with a better solution for me :)

Thank you

VoidZA

Comment: You can't split a string to multiple lines. Use a single line, concatenate separate lines with `+`, or add a backslash to the end of the splitted lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP, removes all line breaks before you echo:

```
$lookNoLineBreaksMom = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $yourString );
```

as a nifty little function, too:

```
function look_mom_no_line_breaks($brokenString) {
    echo preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $yourString );
    // or just return it:
    //   return preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $yourString );
}
```